# Get field from another content type in Views

Tags: views, nodes, 6

I have two content types, 'user' content type where I have some info about user and then 'post' content type.

Now I have a view that gets all 'posts' and shows them correctly but I would need to get image (field_user_image) from 'user' content type. How can I get in views from this another content type this image field?

EDIT: Can I do this somehow on code level in template.php?

Answer (score 1):

I cannot give you a very detailed answer, mainly because it has been too long since I built new things with Drupal 6, but also because I don't know which Views version you are using.

But anyway, the key to your answer is "relationships". Views allows you to define a relationship from one item to another (for instance: `node -> author (user)`) and then query properties of the related item (`node -> author[name]`). You can even chain relationships, so you can query a property of a related item of a related item. This seems to be what you need: `node -> author -> node[field]`.

For more info I recommend that you find some video's or tutorials about views relationships, like these ones:

- http://gotdrupal.com/videos/drupal-views-relationships
- http://drupaleasy.com/blogs/ultimike/2009/07/using-views-relationships-arguments-attachments